# Convert data in milliseconds to date in ext-js without timezone

Tags: datetime, extjs, timezone, client, milliseconds

In ext-js ,
I have a data in millseconds ..eg;850248000000 for DOB field.
it is what i get from server side.

I need to convert this to Date format to be shown in a browser.
Time Zone at the Client Side should not affect the conversion.

Appreciate your help.

kp

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to know would be what the time means(thanks @Teo). If it's epoch time in ms, the following might work for you

```
var d = new Date(850248000000)

console.log(d.toGMTString())

>>>Tue, 10 Dec 1996 20:00:00 GMT VM309:2

console.log(d.toLocaleString())

>>>12/10/1996 3:00:00 PM VM310:2
```

Comment: Normally i would agree but some research should be made to see who's writing this 850248000000 to the database. Custom reference points for milliseconds other than the Unix epoch (1970) come up more often than i would have thought...

Comment: That's true. It would on the developer's hand to figure out what's the time means(epoch or not). On the other hand, I should have add my response to the comment rather than guess what the time is. thanks for the comment.